# Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error while capturing image from gallery Swift

Tags: swift

Im trying to get image from gallery in Swift.

```
 func showPicker(type : UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
        let imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = type
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

then:

```
        self.showPicker(type: .savedPhotosAlbum)
```

However, when i enter gallery on my device and pick photo nothing happen, instead in log it says : `[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error`

How to dismiss gallery and save image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImagepickerView
```

set delegate UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

//in did load
imagePicker.delegate = self

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imgview.image = image

        } else{
            print("Something went wrong")
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```